# Android don't see log of my application but of device are displayed

Tags: android, eclipse, logging, adb, logcat

I can see the phone logs, but when i run the app with some log like `Log.d("LOGIN", "I am in login");` it didn't display it. I try to restart adb, close eclipse and much more, but nothig happens.

I try in terminal:

```
adb shell
cd /sys/kernel/logger/
```

but it say that it is no `'logger'` directory inside of `/sys/kernel`.

The device is a chinese mtk 6577 phone. Is there a way to enable logcat or another app for display logs developing app with the device?

Thank you very much

Comment: Try `adb logcat` or `adb shell` and then `logcat`  With no options specified that should indeed give you unfiltered logs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Chris. I try that and I see all the log of the phone (many errors/warnings), but not my log. The tag "HOME" could be the problem?

Comment: Try your code on the emulator to rule out oddity with the device, but most likely your program never reaches the log call.

Comment: I'm trying and in simulator I can see the logs! So is a device problem...Have you any experience with mediatek processor devices? Thanks